# How to connect Asp.net core Identity user to IdentityServer4 user

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 deployed with a backing SQL server database.
I also have an Asp.NET Core WebAppi services deployed tha is using IdentityServer4 as authority.
Then I have a Typescrip SPA client that uses (for now) IdenityServer4 to login and get JWTToken to connect to the WebAPI.

How to use Microsoft Indentity on the WebApi to manage authorizations. What I mean is, now when I authenticate to IdentityServer I get a User object in my WebApi controllers. This user is tied to the IdentityServer4 and has it's claims. I would like to connect this User to the local Asp.NEt Identity User from my WebApi, so I can manage it's roles and claim specifically for this WebApi.

On The WebApi, I would like to use Microsoft asp.net identity to store locally user, user roles, user claims speciffic to that webApi, and only use IdentityServer4 for authentication. How to map IS4 user to my Asp.NEt Core Identity User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can fetch user's roles from IdentityServer's UserInfo endpoint and do the same thing you are going to do with Asp.Net Identity.

So, After all token's validation operation, you have to check user exists in your database or not. If there wasn't exist then add user to your database.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = "";
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
            {
                var usermanager = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                var user = await usermanager.FindByNameAsync(context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new ApplicationUser();
                    user.UserName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                    //...

                    await usermanager.CreateAsync(user);
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.This is what I was looking for.